# Issue of Passing NSDictionary in AFNetworking Post Request with Swift 2.0

Tags: swift2

Is Anyone having idea how to pass parameters in NSDictionary for AFNetworking in Swift 2.0. I am not able to convert this.
Please suggest

Comment: Can you please share your code?

Comment: let parametersVal:Dictionary<String,String?> = ["passwd":txtPassword!.text,"login":txtEmail!.text]
APIsManager.postRequest("http://testurl.html", parametersVal: parametersVal, succesVal: { (dataVal, statusCode) -> Void in
            }, failVal: { (errorVal, statusCode) -> Void in
            })Error in second line is: "Cannot invoke 'postRequest' with an argument list of type '(String, parametersVal: Dictionary<String, String?>, succesVal: (_, _) -> Void, failVal: (_, _) -> Void)'". So, in this case how we convert Dictionary to NSDictionary